# How do you get a value between "," in JS (comma)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a value that's between, next or before of a comma.

For example, my string is: `"value1,value2,value3,value4"`, sent to JS through PHP (ajax)

How do I just get `value2` and `value4` inside the .js file?

Comment: Instead of sending string, send an object.

Comment: `JS` has `.split()` - PHP has `explode()`

Comment: Are you trying to filter the odd positioned elements? like value2, value4, value6 etc etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    let myString = "value1,value2,value3,value4"
    myString.split(',')
  console.log(myString.split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let szResult = "val1,val2,val3,val4";
let arr = szResult.split(',');
console.log(arr[1]); // val2
console.log(arr[3]); // val4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split() function like that:

```
var arr = yourString.split(",")
// value2
return arr[1]
// value 3
return arr[3]
```

It's pretty simple, I don't think it is really issue for the question here, sorry.